# target the parent row of a particular cell

Tags: javascript

I have a table with a list of records. each row has class "list_request" and has a cell of class "record_approval":

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>name</th><th>date</th><th>id</th><th>group</th><th>approval</th>
<tr class="list_request">
<td>Frank</td><td>2012-2-15</td><td>01</td><td>Account</td><td class="record_approval">Dave Ellis</td>
</tr>
<tr class="list_request">
<td>Ellen</td><td>2012-2-19</td><td>04</td><td>Admin</td><td class="record_approval">Susan Peters</td>
</tr>
<tr class="list_request">
<td>Michael</td><td>2012-2-26</td><td>06</td><td>Admin</td><td class="record_approval"></td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to construct a javascript function that checks whether or not "record_approval" has a value (which value is unimportant), and if so, change the css color value for that row. Essentially, the approved records should have a different color than the unapproved ones.
something like...

```
function check_approval(){
    var checkrow = document.querySelectorAll( "tr.request_list" )
    var checkcell =  document.querySelectorAll( "td.record_approval" )

    for (i=0;i<checkcell.length;i++){  
    if (!checkcell.value){
        this.parentNode.style.color = "ff9900";
    }  
    else{

    }
}
```

is this essentially the wrong approach?

Comment: no, it reports undefined.

Comment: There are a few mistakes there. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistakes I found:

- Unclosed `for` loop (missing closing `}`)
- You're looking for class `request_list`, but on your html it's `list_request`
- You should be using `checkcell[i]` instead of `checkcell`  inside your loop
- Your color hex value should begin with a `#`.
- There's no need to get all rows and cells from an event listener
- It's unclear when you want that function to run. Should it respond to an event?

Also, I'd set a new css class on the row, instead of setting the color directly.

---

Apparently, you're looking for this:

```
var checkcell =  document.querySelectorAll( "td.record_approval" );
for (i=0;i<checkcell.length;i++){  
    if (checkcell[i].innerHTML){
        checkcell[i].parentNode.style.color = "#ff9900";
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/anadij/1/edit

Comment: this works, kinda... it identifies the table header row as the parent and turns all of the th cells #ff9900. So I guess it's just a matter of correctly targeting the containing tr.

Comment: my mistake, I inadvertently set the tr css to #ff9900. this code doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the whole row, or just the approved cells? What are the conditions for coloring, it's not clear.

Comment: the whole row. if there is data (a name) in the approve cell, that row should have color #ff9900 (the particular hex value is unimportant). All other rows (no value in approve cell) should be left alone.

Comment: Sorry, my conditional was inverted, and there is no `value` to check, I'm now checking if the cell contains any html. Added a live demo too.

Comment: I'm choosing this because I know (and can see) that it works. Doesn't work in my situation; I believe because I'm populating the cells with dynamic data. This is a good start though. I'll work out the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. checkcell is an array of elements. you'll want to loop through them, accessing 'checkcell[i]' instead of checkcell.value.
2. your hex color should be defined with a "#" preceding ff9900
3. your for loop isn't closed properly

basically update it s.t.

```
if (!checkcell[i].value){
    checkcell[i].parentNode.style.color = "#ff9900";
} else{

}
```